# Need help in Java with reading doubles in an input file

Tags: java

**Input File:**

John 100000.555

Mary 278.0

Joe 43.7956

Chris .25

Essentially, what I am having trouble with is trying to get the double values integrated into my code, I have tried and searched this up for the past few hours, but have had no luck.

**Here is my code:**import java.io.*;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Treasury {

public static void main (String[]args)throws Exception{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Treasury.txt.txt"));

    System.out.print(String.format("%15s", "Balance"));
    System.out.print(String.format("%2s", ""));
    System.out.println(String.format("%-10s", "Name"));
    System.out.println("---------------  ----------");

    int count = 0;      

    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String name = input.next();
        input.next();
        String s = String.format("%-10s", "                 " + name);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    while(input.hasNextLine())
    {      
        double amount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%15.2f", amount);      
    }

    input.close();

}
}
```

**NOT PRINTING NUMBERS, NEED TO PRINT NUMBERS WITH RIGHT JUSTIFY.**

Comment: I have no idea what your exact problem is, as you are not describing what happens when you try to run that code

Comment: In the first loop, you call input.next()` twice in your loop, once to read the name, and the other call just ignores / discards the value read. The second loop will probably never run because you already read as much input as possible in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is read the next line first as a string and then parse it to a double, I can't try it right noe but it could work:
double amount = Double.parseDouble(input.next());